# Silverlight 3 Button - Text + Image Alignment Problems

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I'm trying to have a button contain both an image text.  Ideally have the text left aligned, while the image is as far right as possible.

So i create a Grid, and add an Image and Textblock to it and set its alignment.  For the life of me i cant get alignment to act as expected.

```
 var gridPanel = new Grid();
        gridPanel.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

        var text = new TextBlock { Text = header, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left };
        text.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        text.Margin = new Thickness(0);
        text.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
        text.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);

        var image = new Image();
        image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../Images/Common/RedFlag.png", UriKind.Relative));
        image.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        image.Height = 25;
        image.Width = 25;
        image.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
        image.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);

        gridPanel.Children.Add(text);
        gridPanel.Children.Add(image);

        button.Content = gridPanel;
```

Both the Image and Text are center aligned for some reason...Is Grid the wrong way to go? I tried StackPanel and setting its orientation to Horizontal but it was the same thing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default the HorizontalContentAlignment of a button is set at "Center"... Just set it to "Stretch" like that :

```
button.HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the HorizontalContentAlignment from Centre to Stretch, like-

```
<Button Name="button" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Edit-
I was originally doing this in the button style as I didn't know about the HorizontalContentAlignment property